# Which was the post-resurrection appearance of Jesus in Galilee that had been foretold?

Tags: catholicism, gospel-of-matthew, gospel-of-john

We see Jesus telling the disciples before he prays in Gethsemane in  Mtt 26:32 :

> But after I am raised up, I will go ahead of you to Galilee.

We also hear the angel telling the woman disciples  in Mtt 28:5-7:

> The angel said to the women, “Do not be afraid, for I know that you are looking for Jesus, who was crucified. He is not here; he has risen, .....Then go quickly and tell his disciples: ‘He has risen from the dead and is going ahead of you into Galilee. There you will see him.’

That message is re-iterated by Jesus himself at Mtt 28:10 :

> Then Jesus said to them, “Do not be afraid. Go and tell my brothers to go to Galilee; there they will see me.”

We  see Jesus appearing to the disciples after his resurrection  twice in an undisclosed location presumably  Jerusalem,  where they had gone to attend the Passover (Jn 20: 19-29)

Later,  we see in Jn 21: 1-14 (NIV)  :

> Afterward Jesus appeared again to his disciples, by the Sea of Galilee. It happened this way:  Simon Peter, Thomas (also known as Didymus, Nathanael from Cana in Galilee, the sons of Zebedee, and two other disciples were together.  “I’m going out to fish,” Simon Peter told them, and they said, “We’ll go with you.” So they went out and got into the boat, but that night they caught nothing. Early in the morning, Jesus stood on the shore, but the disciples did not realize that it was Jesus.

Going by John's account, it was the third time that Jesus was appearing to the disciples after his resurrection . And  this  was presumably the pre-arranged  appearance foretold in Mtt 26:32 and Mtt 28:7. But then , there is a twist in Mtt 28:16:

> Then the eleven disciples went to Galilee, to the mountain where Jesus had told them to go.

See that Matthew  does not discuss the appearance by the Sea  of Galilee as does John.

My question therefore is: According to Catholic scholars, which was the post-resurrection appearance of Jesus in Galilee that had been foretold ?